# jQuery addClass doesn't add class to element

Tags: jquery

I've the following html code

```
<ul class='selectul'>
    <li class='active'><a href='?sortby=views'>by Popularity.</a></li>
    <li><a href='?sortby=recency'>by Recency.</a></li>
    <li><a href='?sortby=alphabet'>Alphabetically.</a></li>
</ul>
```

When any `<li>` element is clicked, I want to add `class='active'` to it. None of its siblings is then allowed to have this class. I tried to do this with the following jQuery code

```
(function(){
    $('.selectul li').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
}())
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm just getting started with jQuery so I apologize if this question is rather basic.

Comment: You should use document ready handler instead of a self-invoking function.

Comment: Your code looks fine, i suspect you need to wrap your code in a document ready event - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: If you are just getting started you should follow this tutorial very closely: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery.

Comment: Also, you can chain the functions `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script is all right. The problem is somewhere else. Once you click the link, the document reload and you do not notice the change of classes.

Try:

```
(function(){
  $('.selectul li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    return false;
  });
}());
```

**return false** interrupts the Click-Event and prevent the reload of the document.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick! However, now my query string doesn't change anymore when I click on the options. And that is a bit of a problem...

Comment: If you are sending a request anyway, then change the active-class on the server side ;-)

Comment: do you mean I should have PHP check for the query string and modify the HTML according to it?

Comment: Exactly, for example: `<? if ($_GET['sortby'] == 'views'): ?>class="active"<? endif; ?>`

Comment: Clear. I'll see if that'll accomplish what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, and I have verified it working @ jsfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/kEfyT/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectul li').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, I tried that but it still seems to do nothing. I know the html source code is not supposed to change but in the Google Chrome Developer tools, I should see this class being added, right? It still isn't... What else could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the page reloads on clicking, undoing the jQuery effect :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for a document ready event as the elements might not be on the page yet.

```
$(function(){
    $('.selectul li').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should code like this

http://jsfiddle.net/3WBvL/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectul li').on('click',function(){

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```